# Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.example.soasec.entities.User.roles[com.example.soasec.entities.Role]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-security

I'm trying to build Secure REST API with authentication using Spring.

I've created the *User* class in the following way:

```
package com.example.soasec.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;


@Entity

public class User extends BaseEntity{

    private String username;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Role> roles;
    private boolean active;


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

The IDE throw me an error at this line `private List<Role> roles;` and when i click it, the following message appears:
*'One To Many attribute value type should not be 'Role'*.

Role class:

```
package com.example.soasec.entities;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    String name;

    Role(){}

    public Role(String name) {this.name=name;}

    public String getName(){return name; }

    public void setName(String name) {this.name= name; }
}
```

Also, I have this problem when I try to compile

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-09-21 19:02:04.782 ERROR 7692 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.example.soasec.entities.User.roles[com.example.soasec.entities.Role]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.example.soasec.SoasecApplication.main(SoasecApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.example.soasec.entities.User.roles[com.example.soasec.entities.Role]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1351) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:874) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:799) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1661) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

How can I resolve the issue?

**Useful informations:**

Java version:11

JDK: openjdk-17

IntelliJ IDEA version:2021.2.2

Spring boot version:2.5.4

Comment: can you post your Role.java ?

Comment: Sure, added it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to fix this.

**1) Make `Role` an entity**

```java
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    String name;

    public Role(){}

    public Role(String name) {this.name=name;}

    public String getName(){return name; }

    public void setName(String name) {this.name= name; }
}
```

**2) Make `Role` embeddable**

In this case, the elements are completely owned by `User`. All operations are cascaded to `Role` list. `Role` does not have its own lifecycle and can not be queried on its own.

```java
@Embeddable
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    String name;

    public Role(){}

    public Role(String name) {this.name=name;}

    public String getName(){return name; }

    public void setName(String name) {this.name= name; }
}
```

You also need to make some changes on `User`:

```java
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity{

    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Role> roles;
    private boolean active;
}
```

Here you can use `@CollectionTable` if you want to customize the collection table. If the `@CollectionTable` annotation is missing, the default values of the `@CollectionTable` annotation elements apply. Reference documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/CollectionTable.html.

Comment: In that case and if my answer was helpful consider upvoting it and/or accept it as the answer so that others can easily understand how to tackle similar issues. Thanks! ;)

Comment: The first one worked but I had also to add “public” before Role() {}, otherwise I got an error

Comment: Sure, I just copied what you had and missed that. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `user` property inside the Role.java with `@ManyToOne` annotation:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    String name;
    Role(){}

    @ManyToOne
    public User user;

    public Role(String name) {this.name=name;}
    public String getName(){return name; }
    public void setName(String name) {this.name= name; }
}
```

And in the User.java, replace:`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` with `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")`

Comment: I tried it, but I get the same identical errors. In addiction in the User.java class on line "@OneToMany(mappedBy= "user")" the "user" word is higlighted in red and moving with the cursor on it I get the message: Can't find inverse attribute.

Comment: Can you try add @Entity annotation on top of Role class?